# Is there a way to designate which shell to use depending on the user?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh

In this context, I have a script that is shared by two users. One user uses bash the other uses zsh. I need this script to use bash or zsh depending on the logged in user. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash if user1
#!/bin/zsh  if user2
```

How would one actually go about implementing this?

Better yet, is there to make a default then use a certain shell only if a specific user is executing the script? Something along the lines of:

```
if user1
then
  #!/bin/bash
else
  #!/bin/zsh
fi
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The shell you use in a script doesn't have to be the same as the one that the user uses interactively.

Comment: @Barmar in this case, both users use the same script simultaneously as it is synced over two machines. The script can't be duplicated for use by the other user.

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with anything. The shebang line has to match how you've coded the script, it doesn't matter what user is using it. If you have zsh-only commands in a script that use `#!/bin/bash`, it won't work properly, and vice versa.

Comment: @Barmar is right. Scripts can be written in _any language_ the computer has an interpreter for, and can be executed by _any shell_ the user chooses to use. I routinely invoke scripts in Perl, Python, bash, and sh throughout the day, even though my shell is actually dash.

Comment: @M.J.Davis even if 2 users execute the same script with the same shell, it will still be 2 different invocations. There is no need to use 2 different shells, if both users want to do the same thing. Internal variables of your script are private for each call, there are no problems. What is more important is the **data** that you write to the harddisk. But there, using a different shell does not help you either.

Comment: Is this really off-topic? I'm not sure I can agree with the close reason -- making an inline interpreter change is _very much_ a programming construct -- and sometimes a useful one -- even though the reason for doing it here is very much suspect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I would have voted to close it as unclear what you're asking. But sometimes there's no perfect choice in the close reason list, we pick something close.

Comment: i find the question highly relevant.  here's why.   more damage than help has been done by teaching the need for sh-bang as (likely no later than) the third instructional point in shell programming.  it belongs in the penultimate lesson along with cron and job-control.   we need to be learning (and therefore teaching) functions rather than "script"s.   if the question was asked previously, where's the link to the response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no good reason to do this. However:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$shell_selected" ]; then
  case "$(id -u)" in
    user1) export shell_selected=1; exec zsh "$0" "$@" ;;
    user2) export shell_selected=1; exec bash "$0" "$@" ;;
  fi
fi

# ...script contents here...
```

Importantly:

- To prevent ourselves from getting into an endless loop, we *export an environment variable* before re-executing ourselves with a different shell, and only re-execute if that environment variable isn't set.
- To actually change shells, we use the `exec` call, which replaces our process-table entry with a different program.

Again, though: There is **absolutely no reason to do this**, and plenty of reasons not to. Your users can each run scripts with a shebang that differs from their natively configured shell, just as users can run a Python script even though their native shell will *never* be Python -- the shebang line controls the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a wrapper script that checks $UID and then invokes the correct version of the desired script.